# Generate Password PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, md5, generator

Im trying to create a PHP page to generate a password and update a record with the new password on the database. There are two tables on the database I have to check the user exists on and I am not sure of the MySQL required to update the fields. Here is what I have so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['rest'])) {

        if (empty($_POST['email'])) { 
        echo "<h2 class='output'>You did not enter an email address</h2>"; 
        } 
        else{ 
        $email = $_POST['email'];   

        mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$localhost) or die ("Couldn't select the database."); 

        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE email='$email'"); 
        $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email='$email'");

        $rowCheck1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
        $rowCheck2 = mysql_num_rows($result2); 
        if(($rowCheck1 > 0) || ($rowCheck2 > 0)){ 

        $newPass = md5( random_gen(8));
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin, student (password) VALUES (".$newPass.") WHERE email="$email"");

}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hey, to the risk of being slightly off-topic, I want to suggest that you please please don't try to generate your own passwords, especially not with something naive like `md5(something)`. Please have a look at something like [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for the sake of your users.

Comment: yes, i need to update the password field of the record with the email inputted from a form.

Comment: Thank you @zi42. This is my first time trying anything like this, well have a look PHPass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the [sql update statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). The insert statement will add a new row to the student and admin tables.

so your code should look something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['rest'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) { 
        echo "<h2 class='output'>You did not enter an email address</h2>"; 
    } 
    else{ 
        $email = $_POST['email'];   

        mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$localhost) or die ("Couldn't select the database."); 

        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE email='$email'"); 
        $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email='$email'");

        $rowCheck1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
        $rowCheck2 = mysql_num_rows($result2); 
        if(($rowCheck1 > 0) || ($rowCheck2 > 0)){ 

            $newPass = md5( random_gen(8))
            mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET password = '$newPass' WHERE email='$email'");
            mysql_query("UPDATE student SET password = '$newPass' WHERE email='$email'");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -5):

Instead of inserting a new row into the mysql table, use "update".

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `admin`,`student` (`password`) VALUES ('$newPass') WHERE `email` = '$email'");
```

Also, added some punctuation.

Edit:
Thanks @zi42 for reminding me, it's generally not a good idea to use MD5 anymore. What's better to use is [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) and "sha256" hash.